# How can I add a blocklist at either the kafka topic level or as a processor in nifi?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, apache-kafka-streams

I have log message data that is being pushed to a kafka topic with a nifi kafka consumer pulling in the message data and routing it to various drops. There are a number of records I would like to scrub based on a set of internal user ID's and IP addresses.  I have a list of about 20 IP addresses and 10 user ID's to scrub.

Is there a way to set a blocklist either in front of the topic that filters the data before it lands and is consumed by Nifi or a way to add this as a processor that would filter the data at Nifi before sinking to various sources?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using NiFi, you could do something like this:

Consume messages with [ConsumeKafkaRecord](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-6-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6/index.html) then use a [QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) to filter messages with a [SQL Query](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html).

`QueryRecord` config would be:

A Dynamic Property `filtered` and a value `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE userid IN (user1,user2,user3) OR ipaddr IN (ip1,ip2,ip3)`

This will give you an `unmatched` relationship for messages that did not match, and a `filtered` relationship for messages that did match. You can then do whatever you want with the two sets of messages.

If you didn't want to hard-code the list of users/IPs in the SQL, you could build it into your flow to pull those lists from an external source then reference them dynmically.